# How to upgrade MSL to 4.0 in JModelica?

Tags: jmodelica

I still use mainly latest JModelica 2.14 that comes with MSL 3.2.2. I would like to update MSL to 4.0.0 that is available at https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary. My installation works to some smaller extent but mainly produce compilation errors in JModelica.  I have done the following:

1. Downloaded the ModelicaStandardLibrary_v4.0.0 zip-file from github.
2. Moved the big folder to the proper place in Windows file system parallell with the old 3.2.2 MSL and changed name of the old to xMSL and changed named to the new 4.0 to just MSL as before. (In this way I do not need to bother about changing MODELICAPATH and can by renaming these folders easily switch between new and old MSL).
3. Compile in JModelica a model that just use the components RealInput, RealOutput and works.
4. Compile in JModelica a model that use RealInput and Sources.CombiTimeTable and gives compilation errors and thus does not work.
5. Also tried models with some other components and brings compilation errors with some similarity as above.

I have also run my models in nightly build OpenModelica 1.20... with MSL 4.0 and have no problems.  So I tend to think the problem is around the installation of MSL 4.0. Also noted here is on Github for MSL some conversion scripts I do not understand if I need to use, or how to use. However CombiTimeTable seems not to be among the components to be addressed.

I would appreciate some guidance, and especially if MSL 4.0 can be used with JModelica 2.14 at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my contact at Modelon AB I understand that JModelica 2.14 do not support MSL 4.0.0. Further it is NOT advisable to even upgrade to MSL 3.2.3 and better to stay with MSL 3.2.2.